# I am trying to interface a HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor with my STM32F407 Discovery board, using bare metal programming, but the sensor is not responding

Tags: sensors, bare-metal, stm32f4discovery

My sensor is not responding to the 10 us pulses I am giving to its Trig pin. The below code uses external interrupts to know whether I am getting any input at all from the echo pin of the sensor and the interrupt is not firing at all.

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
void GPIO_init(void);
void EXTI_init(void);
void TIM2_init(void);
void usdelay(int);
void msdelay(int);
int main(){
    GPIO_init();
    TIM2_init();
    EXTI_init();
    while(1){
        GPIOC -> ODR &= ~(1<<7);
        usdelay(2);
        GPIOC -> ODR |= (1<<7);
        usdelay(10);
        GPIOC -> ODR &= ~(1<<7);
        msdelay(50);
    }
}

void GPIO_init(void){
    RCC -> CFGR &= ~(0x908FUL);
    RCC -> AHB1ENR |= (0x3<<2);
    GPIOC -> MODER |= (0x1<<14);
    GPIOC -> MODER &= ~(0x3<<12);
    GPIOD -> MODER |= (0x1<<28);
    GPIOD -> OTYPER &= ~(0x1<<14);
    GPIOC -> OTYPER &= ~(0x3<<6);
    GPIOD -> PUPDR |= (0x2<<28);
    GPIOC -> PUPDR |= (0xA<<12);
}

void TIM2_init(void){
    RCC -> APB1ENR |= (0x1);
    TIM2 -> CR1 &= ~(0x0010);
    TIM2 -> PSC = 0;
    TIM2 -> ARR = 4;
    TIM2 -> SR &= ~(0x01);
}

void EXTI_init(void){
    RCC -> APB2ENR |= (0x1<<14);
    SYSCFG -> EXTICR[1] |= (0x2<<8);
    EXTI -> IMR |= (0x1<<6);
    EXTI -> RTSR |= (0x1<<6);
    EXTI -> FTSR |= (0x1<<6);
    NVIC -> ISER[0] |= (0x1<<23);
}

void usdelay(int x){
    TIM2 -> ARR = 4*x;
    TIM2 -> CNT = 0;
    TIM2 -> CR1 |= 0x01;
    while(!(TIM2 -> SR & (0x01)));
    TIM2 -> CR1 &= ~(0x01);
    TIM2 -> SR &= ~(0x01);
}

void msdelay(int x){
    TIM2 -> ARR = 4000*x;
    TIM2 -> CNT = 0;
    TIM2 -> CR1 |= (0x1);
    while(!(TIM2 -> SR & (0x1)));
    TIM2 -> CR1 &= ~(0x1);
    TIM2 -> SR &= ~(0x1);
}

void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler(){
    EXTI -> PR |= (1<<6);
    GPIOD -> ODR ^= (1<<14);

}
```

I thought there might be some issues with wiring or supply but after double checking with an arduino it seems everything is working correctly, the sensor, connections and even the supply from STM32 is working as expected. Is it some issue with my clock ? I am assuming a 16 MHz clock as default when no prescaler is applied to the APB1ENR register. I have also tried example codes (one of them: https://ruturajn.hashnode.dev/interfacing-an-ultrasonic-sensor-with-the-stm32f407-discovery-board-using-bare-metal-programming) and still it isn't working.

Edit: So I fixed the issue by using PA0 for interrupt and PC0 for output. Input capture method is also working without any issues.

Comment: As an experiment, try connecting output to input.

Comment: @wek So it seems that even after shorting the input and output, the interrupt is not firing, I don't understand how this is possible. Is it because I put an input and an output pin in the same port ?

Comment: So now I think the issue is why my interrupt is not firing

Answer (score 1):

I used different ports for input and output and that seems to have fixed the issue, I used PA0 for the interrupt and PC0 for the output and this time there are no issues but last time when I used PC6 and PD0 for input and output respectively, the problem persisted, so I don't know if using Port A has fixed the problem or using Pin 0 of both ports has fixed it.

Anyway the problem has been solved.

Comment: Congrats on solving the issue yourself. It's very important to look at the default feature for each GPIO port/pin. Some have a primary, a secondary and every a tertiary function they provide. It differs by board, but the libraries made for each board take advantage of this layout. While you can use any pin for any feature, there is just more coding involved when you don't utilize the built-in features of the library and board. Good luck with your coding.